# how to compile ffmpeg with mingw-w64 toolchain in cygwin environment

Tags: c, ffmpeg, cygwin, mingw-w64

I want to compile ffmpeg project with mingw-w64 compiler in cygwin environment.
I took the following steps:

1. installed cygwin and mingw-w64 package with the setup-x86_64.exe and
   git clone the ffmpeg project from https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git.
2. entered into ffmpeg folder, executed the folloing commands.

./configure --host-os=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-shared --disable-static

make

I found the make command didn't invoke the compiler from mingw-w64, instead it invoked the compiler from cygwin, I have tried the command "make CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc", but it failed with some errors about missing header files as follows:

```
fatal error: sys/ioctl.h: No such file or directory
```

I think these header files have been installed.
which command is correct? direct invocation of command make or the command with CC option? 
I want to use the compiler from mingw-w64 to compile ffmpeg, how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: I don't know about building with mingw-w64 toolchains in a Cygwin environment, but the build is successful in a MSYS2 MinGW-w64 Win64 build environment without any special ./configure options.

Comment: `sys/ioctl.h` belongs to `cygwin-devel` package. Not sure it is used by the cross compiler. I think you need `mingw64-x86_64-headers` and possibly `w32api-headers`

Comment: @matzeri, I have installed both of the headers you mentioned. but I don't know where are the header files located, I searched the whole file system, only one file found, the ioctl.h for cygwin, where is the header files for mingw64-x86_64-headers?

Comment: Use the package search for that info https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/mingw64-x86_64-headers/mingw64-x86_64-headers-5.0.3-1

Comment: unfortunately the sys/ioctl.h header file can't be found in the mingw64-x86_64-headers, I think it is better to compile with msys2, it works.

Comment: @matzeri, do you think how I can solve the problem of missing sys/ioctl.h header file if I really want to compile ffmpeg with mingw-w64 in cygwin? plus I find out that the configure script uses the option " --with-sysroot=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root", in this folder there is no sys/ioctl.h file.

Comment: I'm curious that how the mingw-w64 compiler in msys2 compiles the project successfully, also I can't find the sys/ioctl.h header file in msys2 environment, the search path for header files in msys2 is /mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include, sys/ioctl.h is not located under it.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? Pretty sure that your problem is you're using `--host-os` to cross-compile when you should be using `--target-os`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [apt-cyg](https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg) with:

```sh
# apt-cyg packageof ioctl.h
cygwin-devel: usr/include/sys/ioctl.h

mingw64-x86_64-headers: usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/ddk/usbstorioctl.h
mingw64-x86_64-headers: usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/devioctl.h
mingw64-x86_64-headers: usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/usbioctl.h
mingw64-x86_64-headers: usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/winioctl.h

w32api-headers: usr/include/w32api/ddk/usbstorioctl.h
w32api-headers: usr/include/w32api/devioctl.h
w32api-headers: usr/include/w32api/usbioctl.h
w32api-headers: usr/include/w32api/winioctl.h
```

Thus the file belong to the `cygwin-devel` package.
Install with `apt-cyg install cygwin-devel`.